# Unable to use _TABLE_SUFFIX with nested column

Tags: google-bigquery

Supposing I have table `auction` and have nested column `bid` in the auction table.

Bid has a separate table containing bid price and who made the bid.
I would like to get all the bids information from multiple auction tables in a range of days.

However, the following query will cause error:

```
WITH auction_union AS (
    SELECT *, bid.*
    FROM `auction_*`
    WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20210122' AND '20210125'
)

SELECT *
FROM auction_union
LIMIT 1000
```

Error:

`unrecognized name: bid at [2:15]`

Whilst this will get all the bid tables normally

```
WITH auction_union AS (
    SELECT *, bid.*
    FROM `auction_20210125`    
)

SELECT *
FROM auction_union
LIMIT 1000
```

I would like to know how to query `bid` information in a range of days along with auction info. And if possible, understand what causes this problem

Comment: Hello, can you please share the `auction` table schema (or at least part of it containing the `bid` column)? Is the schema the same for all `auction_*` tables? There might be a problem in the schema of one of the `auction` tables that doesn't contain the `bid` column

Comment: I don't think that's the case because if I do:  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20210125' AND '20210125', it will produce the same error. I will make an edit

Comment: As for the auction schema, it is like:
```name STRING
date STRING
bid RECORD
bid.bid_id STRING
bid.price INTEGER
bid.user STRING```

Comment: thanks, it is strange. I tried to reproduce your example and it is working for me. Here is the link to Pastebin (https://pastebin.com/jgw2pVyw) with my example. Check it out and tell if it simulates your case correctly, please.